# How to embed a Facebook page's reviews into my website

Tags: javascript, html, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to figure out how to have the Facebook reviews listed for my company embedded into a page on my website.  Here is the link for my Facebook reviews:  https://www.facebook.com/jump2itpartyrentals/reviews?ref=page_internal.  I thought that since this feed was available to the public, I could get around having to obtain a Token to access it, but I haven't had any luck with it.

Any help sure would be appreciated.  Thanks!

Comment: You need to paste your code and clarify your question further more.

Comment: I know this is a bit old but if you are using wordpress you can use our Facebook Reviews plugin! Has tons of options including how to get the token you need to make the feed work. http://www.slickremix.com/downloads/feed-them-social-facebook-reviews/

Answer (score 4):

Since there is no Social Plugin for this, and since scraping is not allowed on Facebook, you MUST use the Graph API for showing the Ratings/Reviews on your external Website. The docs offer everything you need to know, including some example code: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.2/page/ratings

You have to use a Page Token. I suggest using an extended one, since it is valid forever. Here's more about Access Tokens, if you don't know how they work:

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens
- http://www.devils-heaven.com/facebook-access-tokens/

Scraping terms: https://www.facebook.com/apps/site_scraping_tos_terms.php

Comment: What makes scraping not allowed on facebook pages? Do they block such requests somehow?

Comment: facebooks official scraping terms ;) - https://www.facebook.com/apps/site_scraping_tos_terms.php

Answer (score -1):

try taking a look at this page in facebook's developers section. it has a bunch of api's for you to use. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/comments This is a comments bar that will display all comments of your wanted url.

Comment: comments? he wants ratings/reviews,comments are something completely different.